# How to use html input value in multiple class? or How to store html input value and use it in multiple class?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

`HTML`

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'doctor:search' %}">
        <input name ="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search..">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            Search
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I like to use input value "{{request.GET.q}}" to be used in multiple class views.

`views`

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Search
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.patient = User.objects.get(username=query)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

[query = self.request.GET.get('q')] in 'SearchResultsView' and in 'PostCreateView' needs same value. How can is use input value from html and use it in both these classes

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can use session variables

# set the value
request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')

# get the value, once the value is set you can get the value from any class
request.session['query']
```

Comment: i'm getting this error [name 'request' is not defined] can you edit that code and show me how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using sessions you can get this way too

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["query"] = self.request.GET.get("q") #None
        return context
```

You can add it on both of views